# How to fix "too many indices for array" when trying to scaler.inverse_transform a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use MinMaxScalar() to invert a numpy array but keep getting that it's too many indices for the array. I've tried changing the range on the array but then I get that it's a 1d array when it's expecting a 2d array.

I've tried changing the range on the array but then I get that it's a 1d array when it's expecting a 2d array.

```
predicted = model.predict(validation_datas)
predicted_inverted = []

for i in range(original_datas.shape[1]):
    scaler.fit(original_datas[:,i].reshape(-1,1))
    predicted_inverted.append(scaler.inverse_transform(predicted[:,:,i]))
```

predicted looks like this:

```
shape: (1, 16)

[[0.32704943 0.3034607  0.30114597 0.27727398 0.31480426 0.26788703
  0.34096426 0.3469543  0.3245615  0.247298   0.28431317 0.20733464
  0.34777245 0.27601427 0.23167448 0.22896819]]
```

I'm not sure what predicted needs to look like in order to invert it.

Comment: Is this the `sklearn` `MinMaxScalar` or something in `tensorflow/keras`?

Comment: If `predicted` is (1,16),why are you using [:,:,i]` to index it?  `inverse_transform` docs says it expects a 2d array, (nsamples,nfeatures) shape.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform

Comment: when I try to use [:,i] to index it says it is a 1d array, this is the sklearn MinMaxScalar

Comment: Yes, `[:,i]` on a (1,16) will produce a 1d (1,) shape array.  That's basic `numpy` indexing.  In `sklearn` terms do you have a clear idea of what are samples versus features?  You seem to be confused over what `sklearn` expects, and what your arrays, such as `predicted`, represent.  As long as you are confused it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot I don't know about your situation, but the error seems straight forward. You're specifying too many indices.

As you indicate with `shape`, `predicted` is 2-dimensional. You're supplying three indices (`[:,:,i]`). That's one too many.

In general, the way to track these down is to note which line is causing the issue and then which part of that line is causing the issue. If you can execute it bit by bit, it should become obvious where the issue is.

Comment: Yes, but only because fixing that issue reveals the next error. The next error is that `scaler.inverse_transform` expects a 2d array. So you need to pass it a 2d array. It's not at all clear what 2d array you're trying to pass it. You could try asking a clearer question about that problem. There are too many unknowns at the moment to help further.